# Excel number in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a problem to be solved in Excel.
I have three columns in Excel.
The DX column is made up of numbers or sections.
The DW column must be the result of a revaluation of the first number available in the DX column and so on.
Once the first value has been obtained, in the DW column there must be another cell which will be the revaluation of the second available number of the column DX, multiplied by the values in the DV cells.
I have to write the formula in DW and then pull it down, without the possibility of changing it.
How can I do?

***Example:***

[image]

I am looking for the solution
Many thanks

Right solution for the problem

2nd screen:
[image]
18958 is 9000 * (1+1,1064..) and 64916,05 is 32458,02 * (1+1)

[image]

Comment: Some expected results would certainly help in understanding what you mean. I feel right now there's only half of an explanation.

Comment: yes, sorry. I did insert another image (2nd screen) in the originary comment. Coudd u please check it? thanks

Comment: Your 2nd link is broken and anyway, imgur is blocked at my place of work. It's better to put the data and expected results *in the body of your question*

Comment: Hi, I did insert the expected results in the body. I am going to insert again it. could u please check it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how ,02 * (1+1) would give 0,05 but let's ignore that for a second..

[image]

**EDIT**: for older Excel and tbh also easier of a formula:
`=IF(ROW(DX3)<4;"";IF(ISNUMBER(DV3);LOOKUP(2;1/($DX2:DX$3<>"");$DX2:DX$3)*(1+DV3);""))`

`LOOKUP` example found [here](https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell)

---

Office 365:
Here's the formula to be pulled down:
`=IF(ROW(DW3)<4;"";IF(ISNUMBER(DV3); LET(pmfFilter;DROP(SORTBY($DX$3:DX3;ROW($DX$3:DX3);-1);1);TAKE(FILTER(pmfFilter;pmfFilter>0);1)*(1+DV3));""))`

You could shorten it by starting like `$DX$3:DX2` but I don't like how that looks so instead, I opted for using `DROP`.
The `SORTBY` sorts the PMf range by row to reverse it and later use `TAKE` on to get the last number to calculate with.
The `FILTER` is because you get 0's in the array from the `DROP(SORTBY`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. for the misunderstanding: 64916,05 is 32458,02 * (1+1). Anyway, my excel is 2016 so there are not as formulas DROP, PMFFILTER and TAKE. could u please give me another option? thanks

Comment: 0,02 * 2 is still 0,04, not 0,05. Regardless, I'll try to get you a different option but Mayukh/P.b/JvdV or someone else will (hopefully) already have an alternative formula for you by the time I get to it. I edited your tags so they might see it quicker.

Comment: thank u very much, I ll wait for your solution! thanks

Comment: Edit made, hope this works for you!

Comment: Hi, it seems it does not work. I did insert a screen in the originary comment, could u please check it? thabks

Comment: Your DX values are missing apart from the 9000 so logically you're not gonna see much with the formula I gave you.. If the new DX number is calculated on the same row-DW number, I changed `ISNUMBER(DX3)` to `ISNUMBER(DV3)`. Should fix it.